# Unable to get vuejs2 and vue-router to work without on client

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router

I am including vuejs and vue router in my page, and created an `app.js` to initialize the router and vue, but the routing does not work, I don't even see the links defined inside as `<router-link to="/foo"> foo </router-link>`

this is a simplified version of code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
    <script src="../build/js/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../build/js/vue-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../build/js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="app">

<div class='nav'>
    <router-link to="/foo">foo</router-link>
    <router-link to="/bar">bar</router-link>
    <router-link to="/tar">tar</router-link>
</div>


<div class="content">
      <router-view></router-view>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

My `app.js` is just a copy/paste of from this vue-router page or this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/yyx990803/xgrjzsup/):

```
// 0. If using a module system (e.g. via vue-cli), import Vue and VueRouter and then call `Vue.use(VueRouter)`.

// 1. Define route components.
// These can be imported from other files
const Foo = { template: '<div>foo</div>' }
const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>' }

// 2. Define some routes
// Each route should map to a component. The "component" can
// either be an actual component constructor created via
// `Vue.extend()`, or just a component options object.
// We'll talk about nested routes later.
const routes = [
  { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
  { path: '/bar', component: Bar }
]

// 3. Create the router instance and pass the `routes` option
// You can pass in additional options here, but let's
// keep it simple for now.
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes // short for `routes: routes`
})

// 4. Create and mount the root instance.
// Make sure to inject the router with the router option to make the
// whole app router-aware.
const app = new Vue({
  router: router
}).$mount('#app')
```

for some reason, I can't see the links at all. I see no error in the console. All files are properly included in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Vue script includes should come right before the closing body tag, not in the head area.

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
       <!-- Your Vue Components Here -->
    </div>

    <!-- Vue Scripts Here -->
    <script src="../build/js/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../build/js/vue-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../build/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Still not working, here is a dump of my index.html ... https://pastebin.com/tuGUNYgP

Comment: Your vue.js script includes should come right before the end of the closing body tag

Comment: Now I get error "Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <script>, as they will not be parsed."

Comment: It should be outside of your #app div, but inside the body tag

Answer (score 1):

i think it is possibly app id should be in the div tag,
check your script links.

I tried on codepen and it worked if you want to look at it

```
 <div id="app">
  <div class='nav'>
    <router-link to="/foo">foo</router-link>
    <router-link to="/bar">bar</router-link>
    <router-link to="/tar">tar</router-link>
  </div>


  <div class="content">
        <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/ResoGuy/pen/Jyzjxg

Comment: Still not working, here is a dump of my index.html ... https://pastebin.com/tuGUNYgP